# MSQL Nested query takes too long to run

Tags: mysql, join

I have a simple nested MySQL query that is taking over 2 mins to run on a DB with only 10K records. Being a first time MYSQL user is there a better way to do this query.

```
Select * FROM OZ.TracknTrace
where LabelNo IN (SELECT distinct(LabelNo) FROM OZ.TracknTrace
WHERE ScanDate BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('22-08-2013','%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('22-08-2013','%d-%m-%Y'))
```

I don't understand joins. Can someone help with changing this query to using joins or is there an even better solution.

Comment: Why select distinct `labelNo` in a date range from a table, only to select everything that falls into that set. Why not just select in the date range?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is equal to this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM OZ.TracknTrace
WHERE ScanDate BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('22-08-2013','%d-%m-%Y') 
               AND STR_TO_DATE('22-08-2013','%d-%m-%Y'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM OZ.TracknTrace t1, OZ.TracknTrace t2
WHERE t1.LabelNo = t2.LabelNo
AND t2.ScanDate BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('22-08-2013','%d-%m-%Y') 
                    AND STR_TO_DATE('22-08-2013','%d-%m-%Y')
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ffeb/1) example. Note index definitions and the execution plan.